# Is it possible to invest on stocks/cryptos with having no Social Security Number in US?

Tags: cryptocurrency, brokerage, online-brokerage, itin, ssn

I am on F-2(student dependent) visa in the US. I want to know if it is possible to have a brokerage account and invest online on stocks or cryptos?

I do not have SSN nor ITIN and some brokerage like Robinhood have SSN requirement. But I am curious to know if there are others will accept this condition and also are safe and good to go?

Answer (score 4):

US brokerages will require a tax id since that's necessary to properly report your earnings. You can issue an ITIN if you're not eligible for SSN, see [form W7](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-w-7) and its instructions.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Can I file the W7 anytime through the year or there is one specific time in year I can do that?  Also, do you know how long it takes to get ITIN in average?

Comment: @WDR follow the instructions on when and how to file. I'm not very familiar with the process, but I do know that it takes time and you're required to submit your passport (or certified copy of it) with your application, so it may be pretty annoying. I also know that the IRS is notorious for occasionally losing passports of W7 applicants. So just FYI. You don't have much choice on the matter though unless you become eligible for SSN.

Comment: @WDR: You can only apply for an ITIN when filing a US tax return, unless an exception applies. I believe that being subject to federal tax withholding is one of the exceptions, but I am not sure whether it applies to your case, since you are not subject to tax at the time of opening the account, but only when you sell.